# Can Account Abstraction eliminate the need for relayers?

Tags: meta-transactions

Can Account Abstraction, with EIP-4337 implementation, eliminate the need for relayers in the case of meta-transactions ?

Answer (score 1):

in EIP-4337, the role of the Relayer in meta-tx is replaced by Bundler. They are similar but different.

Since there are several implementations of meta-tx, like: [GSN](https://opengsn.org), [biconomy](https://docs.biconomy.io/products/enable-gasless-transactions), [infura tx](https://www.infura.io/product/ethereum/transactions-itx) and many others. I will take the GSN for example.

Relayers and Bundlers are similar in the sense that:

- they both pack some kind of messages ([UserOperation](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337#definitions) vs. [meta transaction](https://docs.opengsn.org/#architecture)) from users into transactions
- both of them are the direct gas payers of the transactions

since the implementation details are different, there are many differences, like:

- the message format they receive is different: UserOperation vs. meta-tx
- they get paid differently, bundlers are paid by paymaster or user's deposits in entry-point-contract, while relayers are paid by paymaster contracts(and the word: `paymaster` mean different things in EIP-4337 and meta-tx)
- relayers must registered in the Relay Hub, while any one can start a builder and start submit txs contains UserOperation messages

Answer (score 1):

EIP-4337 aims to create a standard framework for achieving [account abstraction](https://www.stackup.sh/blog/what-is-account-abstraction) with a permissionless and decentralized network. As DiveInto mentioned the network consists of `bundlers`, who accept `UserOperations` and bundle them into transactions for the network. A few projects are already building it, such as [Infinitism](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/) and [Stackup](https://www.stackup.sh/), which both have near production-ready implementations.

This eliminates the need for dedicated relayers for things like metatransactions, gasless transactions, and so on. Instead, you can submit a `UserOperation` to the bundler network via [an RPC call](https://docs.stackup.sh/docs/packages/bundler/rpc-methods).